# How to assign UIcolor to NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsstring, uicolor

I have array of dictionary

```
[
        {
          "price": 0,
          "test_name": "Multislice CT Scan Virtual Bronchoscopy"
        },
        {
          "price": 0,
          "test_name": "Multislice CT Scan Dental"
        },
        {
          "price": 0,
          "test_name": "Multislice CT Scan Joint (3D)"
        },
        {
          "price": 0,
          "test_name": "Multislice CT Scan Lumbar"
        },
        {
          "price": 0,
          "test_name": "Multislice CT Scan Spine - Cervical / Thoracic"
        },
        {
          "price": 0,
          "test_name": "Multislice CT Scan CT Urography"
        }
]
```

And am converting this array of `Dictionary` to `NSString` like by appending \n at the end of each dictionary value

```
Multislice CT Scan Virtual Bronchoscopy  
Rs.0

Multislice CT Scan Dental  
Rs.0

Multislice CT Scan Joint (3D)  
Rs.0

Multislice CT Scan Lumbar  
Rs.0

Multislice CT Scan Spine - Cervical / Thoracic  
Rs.0

Multislice CT Scan CT Urography  
Rs.0

Multislice CT Scan (Arterial + Portal + Venous)  
Rs.0

Multislice CT Scan Abdomen Triphasic Lever  
Rs.0
```

And now I want **Rs.0** string in redColor... How to give red color to that specific string???

Am using static table.. in that am assigning this whole string to single label..

Comment: You can use `NSMutableAttributedString` for that.

Comment: Why does the name of the product and the price need to be in the same string?  Present them in separate label controls and use the `attributedText` property to colour the labels as you like.

Comment: Its a static cell... If I use two labels then value must be assign dynamically right? That's why am using single label... And single string to assign two values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this using this your all Rs.0 will be display as Red color

```
NSString *str = @"Multislice CT Scan Virtual Bronchoscopy Rs.0 Multislice CT Scan Dental Rs.0";

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(Rs.[0-9]*)" options:kNilOptions error:nil];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,strFirst.length);

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:strFirst options:kNilOptions range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

    NSRange subStringRange = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:subStringRange];
}];
self.label.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Akshay Have you try my answer. Fill free to ask any question if you don't get it.

Comment: if price Rs.100 then it not showing red color... What will be the reguler expression for that?

Comment: Ok let me try for that.

Comment: @Akshay i have edited the answer and change the pattern `Rs. 0` with `(Rs.[0-9]*)`. Now try it, it will convert any Rs number in Red.

Comment: Why does the name of the product and its price need to be in the same string?  If this is being presented to the user then they can be separate label controls and you can use the `attributedText` of the price label to colour as required.  Creating a string with the combined text and then using regular expressions to find the different parts again is a truly horrible solution.  You will have lots of bugs and it will look crap.

Answer (score 2):

> NSMutableAttributedString what you looking for.

try this its and sample code

```
 NSString *strFirst = @"Multislice CT Scan Virtual Bronchoscopy";
    NSString *strSecond = @"Rs.0";


    NSString *strComplete = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",strFirst,strSecond];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strComplete];
    //you can change your string color as your need like below
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                             value:[UIColor blackColor]
                             range:[strComplete rangeOfString:strFirst]];

    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                             value:[UIColor redColor]
                             range:[strComplete rangeOfString:strSecond]];



    self.yourLbl.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: am converting array of dictionary to nsstring using for loop...                              packageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@\nRs.%@\n\n",packageString,[package objectForKey:@"package_name"],[package objectForKey:@"price"]];                How to apply this in loop... I have applied but I got error of NSInvalidArgumentException
[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSMutableAttributedString in iOS 6 and above.

Example code:

```
    NSString *strFirst = @"Multislice CT Scan Virtual Bronchoscopy";
    NSString *strSecond = @"Rs.0";

    NSString *strComplete = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n %@",strFirst,strSecond];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strComplete];

    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                  value:[UIColor redColor]
                  range:[strComplete rangeOfString:strSecond]];


   cell.textLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
-(UIColor *)giveColorfromStringColor:(NSString *)colorname
{
    SEL labelColor = NSSelectorFromString(colorname);
    UIColor *color = [UIColor performSelector:labelColor];
    return color;
}
```

Comment: from where to call this method?

Comment: you assigning in label then use it like this:      self.textLabel.textColor = [self giveColorfromStringColor:@"redColor"];

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
- (NSString *)stringFromColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    const size_t totalComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color.CGColor);
    const CGFloat * components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%02X%02X%02X",
            (int)(255 * components[MIN(0,totalComponents-2)]),
            (int)(255 * components[MIN(1,totalComponents-2)]),
            (int)(255 * components[MIN(2,totalComponents-2)])];
}
```